# Datatable: margins in a page

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I got an script and I succeed on copying it to my Google Sheet.
But I would like the margins in the page narrower so more data can be seen horizontally and not vertically. This is how my table is currently being displayed. the column nota has too much data and if it was horizontally more data would fit in the page.
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxQx7QhYXQXaHhRxkHa2z0gT--4ZpPyk7Nd0COvMIM76ceMMGvNX2E_f7ZUINHulZoSNw/exec

```js
//https://www.bpwebs.com/pull-data-from-google-sheets-to-html-table/

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}
 
//GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY
function getData(){
  var spreadSheetId = "1tMODRuz4T5MYVOGtdLV5j5EqX1MKoz4F_RySpr0YLdE"; //CHANGE
  var dataRange     = "Data!A2:F"; //CHANGE
 
  var range   = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId,dataRange);
  var values  = range.values;
 
  return values;
}
 
//INCLUDE JAVASCRIPT AND CSS FILES
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!--INCLUDE REQUIRED EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT AND CSS LIBRARIES-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
 
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?> <!--INCLUDE JavaScript.html FILE-->
  </head>
 
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
          <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
  /*
  *THIS FUNCTION CALLS THE getData() FUNCTION IN THE Code.gs FILE, 
  *AND PASS RETURNED DATA TO showData() FUNCTION
  */
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
 
  //THIS FUNCTION GENERATE THE DATA TABLE FROM THE DATA ARRAY
  function showData(dataArray){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
        //CHANGE THE TABLE HEADINGS BELOW TO MATCH WITH YOUR SELECTED DATA RANGE
        columns: [
          {"title":"Rating"},
          {"title":"Reviews"},
          {"title":"Book title"},
          {"title":"Number of Pages"},
          {"title":"Type"},
          {"title":"Price"}
        ]
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The link to the file doesn't work, 404

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The html page will fill the browser window.  Are you asking how to add horizontal scroll bars?